# Phaser 3 Make the placeholders fit into the white background

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I am having a issue with my project. My project uses Phaser 3 framework, and what the issue I have is that I used rexUI to add a gridtable to make a table with 3 columns, however, the things inside the gridtable is sticking out as shown in the image.

[image]

I would like to shift it such that it would fit perfectly into the grid table but I am not sure how to do so.

The code below is how I add the placeholder into the scene. I tried adjusting the size of the placeholder, but I do not see any changes even if I make the changes extreme

```
let placeholder = this.add
      .sprite(905, 360, "placeholder")
      .setScale(0.6, 0.4);
```

and code below is the code used to create the table as well as add the items into the table.

```
var tabs = this.rexUI.add
      .tabs({
        x: 1103,
        y: 450,
        panel: this.rexUI.add.gridTable({
          x: 1103,
          y: 450,
          width: 977,
          height: 550,
          scrollMode: 0,
          background: placeholder,
          table: {
            cellWidth: 300,
            cellHeight: 255,
            columns: 3,
            mask: {
              padding: 2,
            },
            reuseCellContainer: true,
          },
          slider: {
            track: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 20, 10, 10, 0x737373),
            thumb: this.rexUI.add.roundRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0xbcbcbc),
          },
          space: {
            left: 20,
            right: 20,
            top: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            table: 10,
          },
```

If anyone is able to help me, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm no `rexUi` expert and, you just share a part of you code, but I think you could solve this problem by setting the stroke color and width from the `placeholder` panel.

```
  // placeholder.setStrokeStyle(lineWidth, color, alpha);
  placeholder.setStrokeStyle(10, 0xffffff, 1);
```

here the link: [to the documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/shape-roundrectangle/#color)